# Is uWSGI's reload-on-rss per worker/process?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

Is uWSGI's `reload-on-rss` value per worker/process? The documentation only states:

> reload if rss memory is higher than specified megabytes

For example, if I have the following in my `.ini` file, will the total memory used by limited to ~5GB?

```
processes = 10
threads = 100
reload-on-rss = 512
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html?highlight=reload-on-rss#reload-on-rss), it seems that the amount is per process.